# Is it possible to build Swift code using the Foundation Framework and target linux?

Tags: swift, swift2, open-source, foundation

I know it will be released as open source in the end of the year, however I would like to know, if I create a framework that uses the Foundation framework, will it still be possible to build for Linux?

On the announcement it was said that they would be releasing Swift and a compiler for linux. Will builds of the open source version be limited to the standard Swift library?

I would really like to create a Web Service in Swift to run in Linux, but I need the Foundation Framework (I don't need that to be open source... just to link it to my code).

Thank you!

Comment: No, Foundation won't be available on non-OS X systems.

Comment: @HAS Actually it will: https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation. And there is also GNUstep with its free implementation of Foundation and more.

Comment: @niutech Yeah, now, but at the time the question was asked there was no chance. And even now it is a work in progress and it is not yet really available.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be possible in the future, considering that Apple decided to release the Foundation framework as Open Source too.

"The Foundation Project, providing core utilities, internationalization, and OS independence http://swift.org"

"This project provides an implementation of the Foundation API for platforms where there is no Objective-C runtime."

https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation

Comment: While this is true, Foundation on Linux is largely unimplemented as of late 2015.  You should check the [status page](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation/blob/master/Docs/Status.md) to see the latest on what is implemented.

Comment: You should update this answer. Foundation is now open source and is available on Linux.