# swift-corelibs-dev build-script with --foundation is not working

Tags: linux, swift, foundation

I build swift on Ubuntu successfully (without errors) from scratch with this options:

```
./utils/build-script --release --foundation --verbose-build --build-stdlib-deployment-targets all -l -b -p --skip-test-linux --build-swift-static-stdlib --build-swift-static-sdk-overlay --xctest -c
```

My goal is to have Foundation in static compiled binaries.

As mentioned everything in the build process works fine, but the execution of a simple script as shown below failed.

```
import Foundation

print("Hello Swift.")
```

I get the following error:

```
/bin/swiftc /home/hello.swift -o /home/hello             
/home/hello.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'Foundation'
```

Do you know how to use --foundation on linux?

Answer (score 0):

Foundation framework is currently not supported on non mac environments 
please refer this 
[is it possible to build swift code using the foundation framework and target](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210648/is-it-possible-to-build-swift-code-using-the-foundation-framework-and-target-lin)

Comment: It seems its on road map of apple to bring Foundation for other platforms also
https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation#part-of-swift-30